# How is Assume Supernatural Ability Feat treated if the ability is passive?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Assume Supernatural Ability is a feat that allows a shape-shifted creature to use an ability of its adopted form:

> You learn to use a single supernatural ability of another kind of creature while assuming its form through a polymorph self spell or a similar effect.

It's clear how this interacts with abilities that require actions to be used. However, how does it work when I want to assume a passive ability? I've been looking at the nymph's Unearthly Grace (Su) which passively grants bonuses to AC and attack. I'm a doppelganger, so I would assume this is permitted.

Additionally, the feat bestows penalties when the user activates the ability he is emulating:

> Using this alien ability is disorienting. You take a -2 penalty on all attack rolls, saving throws, skill checks, and ability checks. Additionally, in a stressful or demanding situation (such as combat), you must succeed on a Will save (DC 19) or be unable to use the ability.

Do I suffer these penalties when attacked, entering combat, or am I always suffering penalties as long as I'm shifted into a nymph?

Comment: A doppelganger's Change Shape ability is more like a *disguise self*  spell than a *polymorph* spell. They don't gain any of the physical characteristics, so I'm not sure they are eligible for the feat. Aside from that, what penalties are you referring to?

Comment: @gaynorvader It's a spell. I forget the feat, but there are upgrades for spell-like abilities to supernatural, which is what doppelganger has, a supernatural ability, which would make it a magical change. This is the only requirement for the feat. It is not like disguise self in that it cannot be removed or countered magically and I can cast it at will.

Comment: @gaynorvader also,note, alter self, which is similar to the doppelganger su, is transmutation whereas disguise self is illusion. I don't think an illusion would work, but I am physically altered, which is why you do a sense motive against a doppelganger, not a spot while they are disguised.

Comment: Supernatural Transformation feat is the feat I was thinking of that turns a spell-like ability into a Supernatural Ability.

Comment: The typical doppelganger can't use the supernatural ability change shape to assume the form of a nymph; a nymph's type is fey while the special ability change shape is limited to a "Small or Medium humanoid." (Still a darn good question, though.)

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan According to the rules, humanoids are a general type which Consist of a head, two arms, two legs, and a torso. Get, elf, dwarf...even undead fall into humanoid category. Alter self cannot be used to turn undead because you cannot mimic rot. I'd need to look up where each of those rules are again, I forget.

Comment: While you can play any way you want, according to the rules, humanoid *is* a creature type just like aberration, construct, fey, undead, and a handful of others. An effect mentioning, for example, humanoids (like the spell [*daze*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsDtoE.html#daze)) does *not* mean any creature fitting the *description* of that type but means any creature actually *possessing* that type. Like I said, if you want to redefine things for your game, that's cool, but doing so sends ripples throughout the game.

Comment: Actually, many Fey and Outsiders [share the humanoid form.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoid_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) It has always been that humanoids are described by what I stated since advanced d&d. There are two definitions of humanoid within d&d, the form I noted and the character type. This ambiguity permits a lot of holes, but does allow a player some room. It has never been officially stated that Get are not humanoid, just as mindflayers are aberrations with a humanoid form.

Comment: Consider following the link from *Wikipedia*'s entry on [humanoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoid_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) to its entry on [creature type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_type_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)). If you still think I'm wrong, also consider posing a question (and composing your own answer) about this issue.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan Strictly speaking, humans are not humanoid, then. Are you saying a doppelganger can't become a human?

Comment: While the lack of a human entry in the *Monster Manual* is one of the game's grossest and earliest oversights, the *PH* and *DMG* imply (*via* the ranger's favored enemy table and NPC stat blocks, respectively)—as do later books (as early as the stat blocks in *Sword and Fist*)—that a human, in fact, possesses the type humanoid (and, specifically, the subtype human). Again, I urge you to pose the question rather than continue this in comments.

Comment: @HeyICanChan ["Larger bipeds are giants (see above), and bipeds with more special abilities are fey, monstrous humanoids or outsiders."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_type_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) If we go strictly off that, which you said to look at, then everything with two legs, torso, two arms, and a head will be considered humanoid. If we go off your "strictly humanoid subtype" rules then I'm limited to Kobold, Goblin, and Orc (not humans).

Comment: Seriously, *pose the question*.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you read the  in the *Monster Manual*'s glossary description of the supernatural ability [change shape](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monsterTypes.html#change-shape) (306-7)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Assume Supernatural Ability

A general feat (Savage Species p.30) available to be taken by any creature with the requisite Wisdom Score, and an "ability to assume a new form magically," Assume Supernatural Ability is contentious in its interpretation. This is partly because form altering magic or abilities have been fraught with difficulty, and partly because the feat is not descriptive, and gives no examples for clarity.

#### The Problem with *Polymorph*

> Because Savage Species was published almost [four months prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Species#Publication_history) to the completion and release of the 3.5 [Revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editions_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons#Dungeons_.26_Dragons_v3.5) of Dungeons & Dragons in 2003, and had been in development throughout most of the time of the revision, it has intermediate rules information between the 3rd and 3.5 versions of the game.
>
> Many creatures in 3.0 had *polymorph self* as a spell-like ability (Sp), while others had different, usually supernatural (Su) abilities, such as Polymorph, Change Shape, Alternate Form, or Alter Self, each of which often mimicked *polymorph self*, but also *alter self* or *shapechange*. With the 3.5 Revision, the *polymorph self* spell became the *polymorph* spell, and almost every instance of it, *alter self*, and *shapechange* was removed from creatures' lists of abilities. Instead they often became the precursors of the current Change Shape and Alternate Form abilities. Even then, there were multiple changes to *polymorph*, Change Shape, and Alternate Form until the designers eventually appeared to give up and make the 'Polymorph' sub-school, which they revised at least once more until producing the 4th edition.
>
> For example, in 3.0, Doppelgangers had *alter self* as a (Su) ability at will, Avolakia (from Monster Manual 2) had (Sp) *polymorph self* (humanoid form only) at-will, Succubi had the same (Sp) as Avolakia, Grimalkin (MM2, p122) had (Su) Polymorph (as *polymorph*, into Medium or smaller animals, beasts (revised to animals, usually) and vermin), Imps had (Su) Polymorph (as *polymorph*, 1-2 forms, Medium or smaller), Quasits had (Su) Alternate Form (*also* as *polymorph*, 1-2 forms, Med. or smaller), and the Phasm had (Su) Alternate Form (as *shapechange*, Diminutive-Large).
>
> Each of these creatures got either a form of Change Shape or Alternate Form, except the Phasm, which got its Alternate Form switched from the more powerful *shapechange* to *polymorph*. This seems to indicate to me that nearly *all* form altering abilities are 'similar' to *polymorph*.
>
> Interactions between 3rd and 3.5 form altering abilities are, therefore, to put it in technical terms, an *awful* mess. This highlights why some players will say that most form altering magic that lets a creature appear to be another to meet the '*polymorph self*spell or a similar effect' metric of the Assume Supernatural Ability feat, and others adhere to only converting the words *polymorph self* to *polymorph*.

### Vague Wording is Vague

Another reason that the feat's use is contested is that the benefit is nebulously worded, stating:

> "You learn to use a single supernatural ability of another kind of creature while assuming its form through a *polymorph self* spell or a similar effect..."

The first sticking point is the '...a single supernatural ability of another kind of creature...' clause. The ways that this can be read are usually:

> 'choose one (Su) ability of a creature whose form you can assume, when you assume its form, you may use that ability'

-or-

> 'choose one type of (Su) ability that creatures have, when you assume the form of a creature that has an ability of the same name, you may use that ability'

-or-

> 'when you take the form of a creature, you may use any one (Su) ability that kind of creature normally has'.

The second sticking point is the '...while assuming its form...' clause. The taking of form is not strongly defined, with players debating how weighted the word 'form' is within the rules. Even the supposedly 'weak' shape altering magic of Eberron's Changeling, Minor Change Shape, is assumed to allow the changeling to take the form of a humanoid, as evidenced by the Racial Emulation feat (Races of Eberron, pp.110-111)

> "...When you use your minor change shape ability to assume the form of a humanoid creature..."

Thus, the answer to the question of whether a Doppelganger can qualify for and use Assume Supernatural Ability is very difficult to definitively answer, but I personally would say 'yes'. Ultimately, the players, including the DM, of course, must decide whether to allow it.

In hopes of balance, I'd probably just add in a clause that only if your HD or Character Level are equal to or greater than that of the creature you're appearing as are you able to assume that creature's form, exactly as with form altering spells in 3.5 rules.

## Finally, an Answer!

Regarding the last part of the Benefits section of the feat:

> "...Using this alien ability is disorienting. You take a -2 penalty on all attack rolls, saving throws, skill checks, and ability checks. Additionally, in a stressful or demanding situation (such as combat), you must succeed on a Will save (DC 19) or be unable to use the ability."

This is a holdover from the 3.0 edition of *polymorph* ***other***, which *polymorph self* inherits from. It has a very similar clause, which states (PHB 3.0, pp.236-237):

> "...The new form can be very disorienting. Any time the polymorphed creature is in a stressful or demanding situation (such as combat), the creature must succeed at a Will save (DC 19) or suffer a -2 penalty on all attack rolls, saves, skill checks, and ability checks until the situation passes..."

The feat looks to actually state that you're 'disoriented' (with the same penalties as being 'shaken', by the way...) *the whole time* you're using the creature's ability. Thus if it's an attack, during the attack action, you take the penalty. If it's a constant (Su) defense or ability, you're always disoriented. Additionally, you must make the save or either lose, or be unable to use, the ability in a clinch.

That's why **Improved Assume Supernatural Ability** is in the same book. It has a higher Wisdom prerequisite, but states (Savage Species, pp.35-36):

> "...This feat functions like Assume Supernatural Ability, except that you do not take the -2 penalty on all attack rolls, saves, skill checks, and ability checks when using it..."

Happy Gaming!

Comment: So “this ability” refers to Assume Supernatural Ability itself, rather than the supernatural ability you’ve assumed? Gee, I wonder why *that* was unclear :P Great find.

Comment: The thing that clarified it for *me* is *polymorph other* with which you took the penalty while in the alien form. With this feat, you take the penalty while using the alien ability. Rather than save, you instead become 'disoriented' automatically, and in combat need to make the save or be unable to use it, which would negate the automatic disorientation. With the update to *polymorph*, only while using the ability do you suffer the disorientation, as being *polymorphed* no longer disorients the target. The save, however, is *always* required, even with Imp. Assume Su. Abil.

Answer (score 1):

The Doppelganger's *Change Shape (Su)* ability says:

> A doppelganger can assume the shape of any Small or Medium humanoid. In humanoid form, the doppelganger loses its natural attacks. A doppelganger can remain in its humanoid form until it chooses to assume a new one. A change in form cannot be dispelled, but a doppelganger reverts to its natural form when killed. A true seeing spell or ability reveals its natural form.

Compare the *Polymorph* which says (among others):

> The subject gains the Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution scores of the new form but retains its own Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores.
>
> It also gains all extraordinary special attacks possessed by the form but does not gain the extraordinary special qualities possessed by the new form or any supernatural or spell-like abilities.

I would contend that as intended the Doppelganger's *Change Shape* ability is NOT similar, because it does NOT grant the physical ability score NOR the extraordinary special attacks of the assumed form.

Given the feat:

> You learn to use a single supernatural ability of another kind of creature while assuming its form through a polymorph self spell or a similar effect.

And the feat's pre-requisite:

> ability to assume a new form magically

I would therefore contend that the Doppelganger cannot gain the benefit of this feat.

---

Still, let's imagine that either the GM allows it or you use *Polymorph Self or a similar effect*.

The feat mentions:

> Using this alien ability is disorienting. You take a -2 penalty on all attack rolls, saving throws, skill checks, and ability checks.

There is:

- no mention of the trigger
- no mention of the duration

For an ability usable as a Standard Action, and with an instantaneous effect, the lack of duration is quite troubling. There is little penalty if this only lasts for the duration of the action, since you do nothing else then.

So? Nothing.

The book is silent. I seem to remember that Savage Species is not exactly the most friendly book in that regard.

---

Let's house rule!

I would personally NOT allow this feat to be taken by a Doppelganger.

> **Unearthly Grace (Su)**
>
> A nymph adds her Charisma modifier as a bonus on all her saving throws, and as a deflection bonus to her Armor Class. (The statistics block already reflects these bonuses).

This is much stronger than any feat.

The Paladin, at level 2, gains *Divine Grace (Su)* which only covers the saving throws portion; and the Paladin is a MAD character.

The Battledancer, at level 1, gets to add its Charisma to AC, but only when unarmored. And it's melee class (they need all the help they can get).

The ability to your Charisma modifier to *both* saving throws and AC (on top of regular armor) at all times is worth much more than the cost of a single feat.

It's somewhat broken with *Polymorph*, as it forces you to cast the spell and maintain it, and by the time you can extend it sufficiently or persist it it has lost much appeal. Without the *Polymorph* restriction, however, it is completely broken.

Comment: Alter self does not need to be similar to polymorph, just "magically caused", which a supernatural ability is. As it is a transmutation, and not an illusion, I am ACTUALLY changing so based strictly on what it states it would be permitted. I know it sounds broken, but my doppelganger kinda sucks and needs AC. The DM has stated it would be permitted, but I wasn't certain how to play the passive abilities since there's no activation.

Comment: Assume Supernatural Ability is one of the quickest ways to break the game into itty bitty pieces, and is used in a lot of theoretical-optimization tricks.

Comment: @NationWidePants: The feat text says *Polymorph self or similar effects*, so per the rule it would probably not be allowed; however it is indeed within your DM purview to house-rule, if (s)he determines this is better for the game. In your stead though, I would actually ask a question posting your character statistics and asking how to improve its survivability, there are really good players on this "board" (notably KRyan, who just commented above) and they could probably help you.

Comment: @KRyan: I would be interested on your reading of the trigger/duration of the penalty mentioned by the feat. It seems really incredibly vague to me.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It is, and I agree with your answer. I do not see any clear way to determine what the feat is supposed to do with any certainty.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Under requirements for the feat it only says you need a magical based ability to alter self. It does not state polymorph in the requirements.

Comment: *You learn to **use** a single supernatural ability of another kind of creature while assuming its form through a* polymorph self *spell or a similar effect* sounds like the creature'd have to, y'know, *do something* (besides, like, merely exist) to invoke the supernatural ability. Just sayin'.

Comment: @NationWidePants: The requirements portion tells you whether you can pick the feat or not; not whether you benefit from it or not. For example, the *Power Attack* feat requires Str 13, so assuming you have a Strength score of 13 or more you can pick it, but you only gain its benefit when you decide to use it *and* reduce your Attack Roll accordingly. And similarly you only gain the benefits of *Assume Supernatural Ability* while under the effect of a *Polymorph Self spell or similar effect*.

Comment: I suppose the real difference in our approach is "What does it mean by 'similar'"? I think we can all agree that everything in savage species was too open-ended. Anyway, I'll try to convince the DM to allow me to roll on use only when I take damage, since that's when AC is normally applied, and since it's similar to a Dex check, I'd be using it to dodge.

Comment: @NationWidePants: If you take -2 to AR any time you are attacked or need to save, it essentially means throughout the combat. That's quite penalizing :x

Comment: Yes, but it grants a +2 to attack (Beautiful Grace) so those negate each other. I essentially only get -2 to my ability scores and a +4 to AC (19 CHA). I'm not trying to break the campaign, just get some bonus, since I can't use magic items, really (character flaw) :x

Comment: @NationWidePants: We don't seem to be arguing about the same ability; I don't see any *Beautiful Grace* ability in the [Nymph block](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/nymph.htm). Do you have the 3.0 version maybe (I don't). Note that it's not -2 to ability scores but -2 to ability checks (you don't lose 1 HP/level, as -2 Con would imply). Initiative is an ability check, for example.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's called "unearthly grace". I'll fix my post.

Comment: But it's "only when used" so I assume that I wouldn't suffer most penalties, except for a round in which my AC came into question. So for that round I would take a -2 for checks for that round. Initiative wouldn't come into play unless the attack instigated initiative, which would suck.

Comment: @Matthieu M. You're also forgetting, every time I need to "dodge" I'd need to roll DC 19 to use the ability. Even if it fails I'd still get -2

Comment: Using this ability is disorienting, take these penalties" implies to me that any time you are gaining a benefit from the ability, you suffer the penalty of disorientation. Granted, thats not RAW, but sounds like the probably intent.

Comment: @DrewMajor: Sounds too, but as I mentioned it does not seem to make much sense when the effect of the ability is "instantaneous". For example, imagine a supernatural ability which lets you heal yourself as a Standard Action. At the end of your action, you are healed and no penalty apply? Maybe, but it does not seem like much of a penalty...

Comment: Yea, good point. would probably make it last that round then. so maybe, "you suffer penalties for any round in which you gained a benefit?" then we have mild penalties for healing yourself, but depending on the heal amount etc, may or may not be worth it.

Comment: I think we're all in agreement. So, would you say I am right, that an ability that strictly affects AC is only used when a calculating of AC becomes necessary and penalties are provided for that round?